# Lag with camera movement

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, lag, frame-rate

I have a character that move in Update with this line of code.

```
characterController ch;
ch.Move(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * speed);
```

and a camera follow it with this line of code.

```
CameraPosition = Vector3.SmoothDamp(CameraPosition, VectorTemp, ref velocityy, smoothTime);
```

and I put 75 sphere for generating polygon.
my test phone is Lg g4 and when scene run I see my frame rate is 50 and static spheres don't move smoothly(because camera move).is this just because of 60k polygons?
my test scene is very simple and I don't want see any lag. I test camera with Lerp and get same result
I add two screenshot for more clarity

[moving my character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkxua.png)

[camera follow character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pneqU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the syntax in LateUpdate, not Update

```
CameraPosition = Vector3.SmoothDamp(CameraPosition, VectorTemp, ref velocityy, smoothTime);
```

Since LateUpdate is called once per frame after Update, you should ensure that the calculation for the camera is processed after the character movement calculation is completed in Update.

Comment: I use that in LateUpdate. but i think maybe my polygon for G4 is high. because in profiler render time is high. even a camera simply goes to right and left and some sphere in front of it (totally 70k poly count ) shows discrete movement in some frames.

Comment: First of all, since the LG G4 model is a 2015 model, it is important to keep in mind that performance problems can occur enough.

However, if 75 spheres are used to express polygons, it is recommended to optimize and convert the polygon into a single object through Blender, etc. and test it.

Comment: I use those because want a simple scene and after seeing status in the game view I decided to decrease drawcalls so create a new material for all of them and bached them. but Lag Exist. I want to khow why in this so simple scene we see Lag? because in my main project I have same issue.

Comment: It is difficult to analyze the issue because I am not fully aware of your project situation.

Is the above camera position setting the only logic that exists within the project?

I think you need to see which part of the Unity Profiler is responsible for the largest portion of runtime operations

Comment: yes character simply move with camera controller and camera follow it with smootdamping without anything else. do you want I take 3 screenshot. one player.another camera and another from game view

Comment: Sure. Take a screenshot and edit the post and I'll check it out. I hope I can give you a solution

Comment: some problem accrued and i can't do the thing. my question in the case of movement was slow and I set the fps to 30  can see  smooth movement without lag and if the movement of camera was  very fast even with 60 fps I must see the lag